# php schedule email so many days before a date stored in db

Tags: php, cron, schedule

how would i go about scheduling an email to go out so many days/weeks before a certain date?

I have a cron job setup for a reminder service i am creating. At the moment the cron job sends out the email reminders on the day. I would like to send the email reminder out lets say 2 weeks before the date that's stored in the database.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Couldn't you just store the date that you want the email to go out in the database as well?

Comment: edit your cron job settings!

Comment: SELECT * FROM XXXX WHERE date_field > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK);

Answer (score 1):

The logic for this you pretty much already have in place, if your sending out the email on the day of, then simply change the date that it should be checking from today, to a date two weeks in the future.

Comment: Just remember to update the database to reflect that the email has ben sent, for example by adding a 'is_sent' column and update that after sending the email. This way you can A) check which emails have been sent and B) prevent emails being sent multiple times